# why does angular 2 provider {useValue: ...} clone objects?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Angular 2 advanced testing doc:

```
userServiceStub = {
  isLoggedIn: true,
  user: { name: 'Test User'}
};

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [ WelcomeComponent ],
// providers:    [ UserService ]  // NO! Don't provide the real service!
                                  // Provide a test-double instead
   providers:    [ {provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceStub } ]
});

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WelcomeComponent);
comp    = fixture.componentInstance;

// UserService actually injected into the component
userService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UserService);
componentUserService = userService;
// UserService from the root injector
userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
```

It seems that the service, userService form injector.get() and userServiceStub from we explicitly created are different Object.

```
it('stub object and injected UserService should not be the same', () => {
  expect(userServiceStub === userService).toBe(false);

  // Changing the stub object has no effect on the injected service
  userServiceStub.isLoggedIn = false;
  expect(userService.isLoggedIn).toBe(true);
});
```

The doc say that the `userService` here is a copy of `userServiceStub`. Is that means that Angular 2 DI treat all `{provide: someting, useValue: someValue}` as clone a new Object frome `someValue`? Why DI system not use `someValue` directly?

Related github [issue](http://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/2910) of Angular.io.

Comment: Did you provide `UserService` in the `WelcomeComponent` as well?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I provide normal userService in root appModule. My question is that why not injector inject the userServiceStub directly here, but a clone of it. There seems to be no matter with the original userService in appModule.

Comment: I doesn't inject a clone. DI never clones. Hard to tell what exactly is going on in your code. Can you provide a Plunker to reproduce?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This test example is from [angular doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#atu-intro). And the code is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) in app/welcome.component.spec.ts.

Comment: The Plunker in `here` link doesn't contain anything meaningful.

Comment: Qoutes from doc: "Surprisingly, you dare not reference the userServiceStub object that was provided to the testing module in the body of your test. It does not work! The userService instance injected into the component is a completely different object, a **clone** of the provided userServiceStub."

Comment: sorry, I fixed it, [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/SoheWbtnAPtDFTGQCEmy?p=preview)

Comment: I assume this is because there are two `userServiceStub`. One inside `beforeEach` and one outside of it. Way too much code to investigate closer. I created https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/2910

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular2 DI maintains a single instance per provider. If a key (type, string or OpaqueToken) is provided multiple times you'll get multiple instances.

In your example `UserService` is provided by the testing module and DI will always return the same instance from this module, but if there is a provider with the same key closer to where the dependency is request (for example on the component itself, then an instance from this provider will be injected.

To override the behavior for the test there are different way, depending on the exact use case.

One example:

```
TestBed.overrideComponent(comp, {set /* or add */: 
    {providers: [/* new providers here */]}
});
```

**Update**

There is a related open issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10788
Seems this actually doesn't work as expected.